# connect react-native, springboot

Tags: spring-boot, react-native

I want to link "react-native" and "spring boot". However, most communities are only dealing with how to link "react" and "spring boot". Then I'd like to ask you if there is a way to link "react-natvie" and "spring boot".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by linking react-native and spring boot? Do you mean that you have react-native app, and your backend service is spring boot?

In that case, spring boot provides restfull http(s) APIs just like any other backend, and you can access those APIs from react-native multiple ways. One of the most common and out of the box way is applying the fetch api, that react-native provides: https://reactnative.dev/docs/network#using-fetch

There's also nice tutorials in web on how to setup spring-boot, like this: https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/